# I have written a abasic constructor code in Solidity but I am getting this error. Is it the version issue?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.17; 

contract MyConstructor {
    
    // string str; //declaring state variable ; 
    
    // constructor() public {    //creating constructor to set value for "str"
    //     str = "bye" ; 
    // }
    
    // function getValue() public view returns(string memory) {
    //      return str;  
    // }
    
    //DIRECT INITIALIZATION 
    
     uint data ; 
     
     constructor(uint _data) public {
         data = _data ; 
     }
     
     function getData() public returns(string memory) {
         return "hello world"; 
     }
}
```

creation of MyConstructor errored:

```
Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid BigNumber string (argument="value", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.4.1)
```

Comment: That's not a smart contract error, that's a typescript error. Share your ts code.

Comment: Please share the deploy code to see how are you interacting with the contract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because you must specify a value in the constructor when implementing the contract. If you do not pass a value, the contract will throw this error. I attached an image with your code working in ide remix.

Remix ss with code working:

[image: remix ss with code working]

Comment: Please include any relevant information [as text directly into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), do not link or embed external images of source code or data. Images make it difficult to efficiently implement the given solution as they cannot be copied and offer poor usability to future users as they cannot be searched. See: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/15497888)

Comment: I don't understand, I just put his code into the remix IDE and compiled the smart contract, I didn't add any extra code

Comment: Oh, yeah I got it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @WomanInBlockChain could you mark it as the correct answer? because this error exists since solidity version 0.5 and has no clear answer, I think it would help other people

peace out

Comment: Definitely! Solidity has a lot of changes after the 0.5 version and in the 0.8 version.